# Is "mine's" a valid contraction?

Tags: grammar, contractions

Not *mines*, but **mine's** (mine is). As in, "You cooked a good turkey, but **mine's** better."

Comment: Yes, it's fine.

Comment: Most definitely yes in spoken English. I wouldn't use it in academic writing (but that may be just style?).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but...

On the one extreme, just about any contraction is valid.

On the other extreme, there is a certain set of extremely common contractions (the negatives of auxiliaries in particular) that everyone agrees are good English, and after that you will find some people objecting, if only as a matter of taste.

The contraction of *’s* for *is* is probably the next safest. Combining it with a genitive makes you slightly more likely to have someone object (because they argue it could be confused with genitive *’s*) though that would still be more a matter of taste than correctness.

As such, I'd have absolutely no qualms about using it in informal English, but I might consider expanding the contraction in formal English; not so much to be correct, as to be inarguably correct.